# Reference items within placeholder control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to reference the following text nested within a placeholder control. I'm able to get the "text" textbox but the IF(childCnt is textbox) condition fails on the "title". I'm guessing it's due to the first textbox being nested within a DIV but now sure how to resolve. (See screenshot)

[image: Quick Watch - What i'm trying to call]

```
foreach (Control cnt in phInitiatives.Controls)
        {
            foreach(Control childCnt in cnt.Controls)
            {
                if (childCnt is TextBox)
                {
                    string controlID = childCnt.ClientID.Substring(3);
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)childCnt;

                    //string title = tb2.Text;
                    string text = tb.Text;

                    //updateInitiatives(controlID, title, text);
                }
            }
        }
```

-- UPDATE -- 
Not sure if this will help?
 Here is the output HTML. I'm able to get textarea (txt1) but not the input(lbl1)

```
<div class="initiative">
<div>
    <input name="lbl1" type="text" value="Try" id="lbl1" class="labelCSS">
    <a onclick="javascript:return confirm('Confirm Delete?');" id="btn1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btn1','')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
</div>
<textarea name="txt1" rows="3" cols="20" id="txt1">Test text **</textarea>
<br><br>
```

Comment: The is operator checks if an object can be cast to a specific type. the childCnt is a type of controls not texbox?

Comment: Correct. The 'text' is being casted to textbox so that i can get the value. That part is working correctly for 'text'. Just wondering how to reference the piece in the screenshot

Comment: I don't see "title" anywhere. Can you be a little clearer on what's going on?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but are you simply trying to retrive the text from a control?

Comment: @itsme86 im not sure how to get 'title' 

I'm parsing a  dataset where for each row i'm adding two textboxes (one for the title and the other is text). The above code is for an onclick method, where i'm trying to fetch the information for the controls within the placeholder (phInitiatives).

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fixed by just removing the nested div.